# Ternary operator for tableCell description strings?

Tags: swift, conditional-operator

just want to simplify the else statement with a ternary expression, because the **description** is the only change in the code

```
if LaunchDarklyEnvironment.isPromoCodeAfterRegistrationForExistingUserEnabled() == true {
                    let descriptionCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: ScoreCardStyledPrimaryTableViewCell.reuseID) as? ScoreCardStyledPrimaryTableViewCell
                    descriptionCell?.configure(withTitle: "promo_code_after_registration_description_header".localized, description: "promo_code_after_registration_description_short".localized)
                    cell = descriptionCell
                } else{
                    let descriptionCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: ScoreCardStyledPrimaryTableViewCell.reuseID) as? ScoreCardStyledPrimaryTableViewCell
                    descriptionCell?.configure(withTitle: "promo_code_after_registration_description_header".localized, description: "promo_code_after_registration_description".localized)
                    cell = descriptionCell
                }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the only thing you're changing is in the descriptionCell?.configure section?

If so, one of the easier ways to do it is to establish a few variables first:

```
let shortConfiguration = "promo_code_after_registration_description_short".localized
let normalConfiguration = "promo_code_after_registration_description".localized
```

Then, you can use the ternary operation in the descriptionCell configuration:

```
let descriptionCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: ScoreCardStyledPrimaryTableViewCell.reuseID) as? ScoreCardStyledPrimaryTableViewCell
                descriptionCell?.configure(withTitle: "promo_code_after_registration_description_header".localized, description: LaunchDarklyEnvironment.isPromoCodeAfterRegistrationForExistingUserEnabled() ? shortConfiguration : normalConfiguration) // <-- Add it right here
                cell = descriptionCell
```

(You don't need to add " == true", given that the conditional will look for that anyway, so just adding the function (which I assume returns a Bool) is enough to get the ternary going)

Comment: thank you so much I didn't understand the Ternary but now I kinda do reading your code thank you for real